# Creating a div rectangle with a slanted right side with curved corners

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a call to action that has curved borders, with a diagonal edge on the right hand side as shown in the image below...

[image]

It cannot be a fixed width or height as the copy will need to be editable and fit any text that is entered. I feel like I have tried anything and everything and I just can't get this to work - I have tried to use it as an SVG, but it isn't working as sometimes it needs to be over two lines etc.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

skew transformtion can help you here:

```css
.box {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -2px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> text </div>
<div class="box"> more text </div>
```